# MYSQL SELECT value AS YEAR(CURDATE)

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to get data from table, as shown on the code. Instead of ThisYear and LastYear; I want to display Year number depending on current year. I want to try use something like "Year(curdate())" and "Year(curdate()) - 1"; and column headers will be 2017 and 2016 instead of ThisYear and LastYear.

```
  SELECT Months AS Months, 
    SUM(if(Years = Year(curdate()) AS ThisYear, 
    SUM(if(Years = Year(curdate())-1, in_amount, null)) AS LastYear, 
    FIELD(Months, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December') AS `FIELD(Months, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')` FROM ao_vw_revenue GROUP BY Months ORDER BY FIELD(Months, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Your query is some how "complex". Why don't you filter the current year's data from `ao_vw_revenue` with a `where` condition?

Comment: Do add an example of the expected result.

Comment: Current result: Column headers; ThisYear LastYear. Expected result: 2017 2016. I want all this to happen at a query level. If year is 2018, then ThisYear should be 2018